# Found these codes but unsure what each line means. (Android: URL, stream, image)

Tags: android, url, bitmap, stream, compression

I have came across but not really sure how each line of codes really do. I hope that I can enlightened on what each line of codes mean.

```
  URL url = new URL(urlPath);
  stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
  fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 5, fos);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining lines of code and does not concern a real problem encountered by the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an URL object with url is the urlPath
2. Connect to the URL and get an InputStream from the connection
3. Decode the stream to a Bitmap image
4. Create a FileOutStream for write file
5. Compress the image with parameter: {format: JPEG, quality: 5(which mean low in scale 0-100), outstream}

So, the purpose of these code lines is to compress an image from the URL.